# Disable a button when the one button is pressed, enable after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 button that load some data, each button take some time to load. so i want to disable the other button for like 10 seconds or until the other button finish rendering.

when one button is clicked, the other button should be disabled for 5 seconds and reenabled after that. how can i do that?

```js
$(function() {

  var clicked = false;
  var first = $('#but1');
  var second = $('#but2');

  first.on('click', function() {
    clicked = !clicked;
    if (clicked)
      second.attr('disabled', 'enabled');
    else
      second.removeAttr('disabled');
  });

  second.on('click', function() {
    clicked = !clicked;
    if (clicked)
      first.attr('disabled', 'enabled');
    else
      first.removeAttr('disabled');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but1">but1</button>
<button id="but2">but2</button>
```

Comment: Post code please. Show this markup you're describing along with your attempts at solving thx. Also, this is just javascript, not computer science or web-dev-server

Comment: updated code now thank you

Comment: See [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). How do the buttons load data? You might be able to hook into a "done" callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make it relative and avoid id's by grouping the buttons. Though, this is just academic. If you're actually waiting for data to load, you should wait until the data is loaded before enabling the button - which is easy enough if you show that code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggles button').click(function() {
    $('.toggles button').not(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('.toggles button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }, 5000)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='toggles'>
  <button id="but1"> button 1</button>
  <button id="but2"> button 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: this code work wait for the button for a certain amount of time?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. What exactly do you need this to do?

Comment: i thought you meant for 2 buttons, the other button would be disabled when one data finish loading, but your code set a time for it?

Comment: Yes, your question seemed to imply you wanted to wait for a certain time period. But in reality are you wanting to wait for an async function (like ajax) to complete? It was unclear

Comment: oh okay, i thought ur code is doing it like waiting for it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {

  var first = $('#but1');
  var second = $('#but2');

  first.click(function() {
    if (!second.prop("disabled")) {
      second.prop('disabled', true);
      setTimeout(function() {
        second.prop("disabled", false);
      }, (10 * 1000));
    }
  });

  second.click(function() {
    if (!first.prop("disabled")) {
      first.prop('disabled', true);
      setTimeout(function() {
        first.prop("disabled", false);
      }, (10 * 1000));
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but1">but1</button>
<button id="but2">but2</button>
```

You want to use `.prop()` to manage element properties such as `disabled`. Please see: https://api.jquery.com/prop/

You can also use `setTimeout()` to execute a code snippet after a specific amount of time has passed. See more: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp